# Can't read Bengali Text from Pdf by iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#

I Have read all texts from English PDF accurately if PDF file contains no image.I have used iTextSharp dll for this purpose.pdfreader also accurately count all pages of the PDF & give me good results for English but I can't read Bengali texts from it.Can anyone help me?

```
    public void ReadPdfFile(string fileName)

    {

           string strText = string.Empty;

           StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

       try

{

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)fileName);
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)

  {


  ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();


  string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

      text.Append(currentText);

            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = text.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Could you provide the pdf containing the Bengali text you would like to read?

Comment: Bengali texts are texts or images?
Did you change the language settings to BNG? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11040/Multiple-language-support-for-MFC-applications-wit

Comment: Yes I Can provide it.